# combining IDs under GROUP BY?

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have an sqlite table "log" that looks like this:

```
ID     p_id     viewer
----------------------
1      1        100
2      1        200
3      1        300
4      3        550
5      3        230
6      5        420
7      2        320
8      2        203
9      9        10
10     9        55
```

And I want to get the average viewers from each p_id. That'd be

```
SELECT avg(viewer) FROM log GROUP BY p_id
```

**But** I want to treat p_id 1 and 5 as the same, so I'd get the average viewers of p_id 1 and 5 combined. How do I do that? Note that the table is much larger, and I need to treat two p_id's as the same multiple times. Can I still do a "group by" to achieve this, or are there other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it works with mySQL at least.

```
SELECT avg(viewer) FROM log GROUP BY CASE p_id WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE p_id END;
```

**Edit:** When using an alias-table named 'aliases' with the fields 'alias_from_id' and 'aliased_as':

```
SELECT
CASE ISNULL((SELECT aliased_as FROM aliases WHERE (alias_from_id = log.pid))) 
WHEN 1 THEN log.pid ELSE aliased_as END AS the_id,
SUM(value) AS value_sum
FROM log
LEFT JOIN aliases ON (alias_from_id = pid)
GROUP BY
CASE ISNULL((SELECT aliased_as FROM aliases WHERE (alias_from_id = log.pid)))
WHEN 1 THEN log.pid ELSE aliased_as END
```

I've tested this with mySQL and it works like a charm. It might be possible to simplify this SQL-query a bit but this is the best I can do at the moment :)

**Edit2:** Changed ISNULL to the corresponding SQLite `IFNULL` function

```
SELECT
IFNULL((SELECT aliased_as FROM aliases WHERE (alias_from_id = log.pid)), log.pid) AS the_id,
SUM(value) AS value_sum
FROM log
LEFT JOIN aliases ON (alias_from_id = pid)
GROUP BY
IFNULL((SELECT aliased_as FROM aliases WHERE (alias_from_id = log.pid)), log.pid)
```

I don't know if SQLite supports the AS keyword, if it doesn't then just remove that keyword - the functionality should be the same.

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. Thanks! This leads me to a followup question, though: How do I do this for N numbers of p_id aliases? I have an alias table storing the old and new p_ids I want to combine, can I use subqueries for this?

Comment: @Conti It took me a while but I found your problem very interesting so I spent some time on it. I think I have solved it. If this works for you, please upvote my answer and accept it as an answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. It seems to work in mySQL, but unfortunately sqlite does not support the "ISNULL" function. It does have "ifnull" and "nullif" functions, but both require two arguments and so cannot just be replaced in this case, and I admittedly do not understand your query enough to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: @Conti changed it to what I believe is the correct SQLite syntax. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: Yay, finally it works. There's a "," missing in your query, which yielded me a rather useless error message ("error near "(""), but apart from that your solution is spot on. Thank you! Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation yet to upvote your question. :/

Comment: @Conti You have enough reputation now? :)